# CSS create border on hover arround filled circle with empty space between circle and border

Tags: css

I have a problem to create those elements together with CSS only. I have created a small white filled circle. But I want that this circle gets a white round border on a `:hover` effect.

Thats how it should look like on `:hover`:

[image]

I found a few ideas here but none of them seem to work. I tryed to use `outline` but at the end I feel like it has to be done with `box-shadow`?

At the moment I have this result:

[My Result (Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/qvjs66v5/)

An alternative solution would be to load images. I could create this image and simply show it on `:hover`. But thats not best practise, I would like to know how this goal can be achieved via CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two box shadows instead of one:

```css
.navi-dots li {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  /* Safari, Chrome */
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  /* Firefox */
  border-radius: 50px;
  /* CSS3 */
}

.navi-dots li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #000, 0 0 0 7px #ffffff;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled navi-dots">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

And just for fun...

```css
.navi-dots li {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  /* Safari, Chrome */
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  /* Firefox */
  border-radius: 50px;
  /* CSS3 */
  
  transition: all .2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #000, 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
}

.navi-dots li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #000, 0 0 0 7px #ffffff;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled navi-dots">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: FWIW you should be able to replace `box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #000, 0 0 0 0 #ffffff; with box-shadow: none;`

Comment: You are probably correct. I tend to set an initial value that makes sense for the transition as I think `none` used to cause issue in the early CSS3 days. Habit I guess

Comment: @Turnip I just tried it  and actually I was surprised to find a subtle difference between them.. http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/KzyEYY .... so I guess I take my first comment back ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use css `:before` property for this here is the complete code with working example https://jsfiddle.net/qvjs66v5/1/

```
.navi-dots li {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    /* Safari, Chrome */
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    /* Firefox */
    border-radius: 50px;
    /* CSS3 */
    position:relative;
}
.navi-dots li:before {
  position:absolute;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  top:-6px;
  left:-6px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  display:none;
  content:"";
}
.navi-dots li:hover:before {
   display:block
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```