# Circular border with spacing on hover

Tags: html, css

This will be easier to explain with a picture, see here is what I want to achieve.

[image: Hover]

When the mouse hovers over the box, I would like to draw a circular border around the grey image. The image has itself has been cropped with a clip path like so:

```
clip-path: circle(65px at center);
```

The rest of the markup is as follows:

```
<div class="artist-card">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130" alt="artist name"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do it myself by adding a `:hover` condition to the box, and then targeting the `.image-wrap` with some `padding: 5px;` and a `border-radius: 50%;` but things didn't go as I expected.

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi hope this does what you want. I used `pointer-events: none` on the `.image-wrap` and `pointer-events: auto` on the `img` to have the border trigger only when hovering over the img.

```css
img {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  clip-path: circle(65px at center);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.image-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.artist-card {
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: grey;
  width: 155px;
  height: 155px;
}

.image-wrap:hover {
  border-color: yellow;
}

.artist-card:hover .image-wrap {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="artist-card">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130" alt="artist name"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice, but sadly not what I'm after. I want the **hover to be on the surrounding dark-grey box** and not the image. Because I also want to lighten the colour of the grey-box on hover.

Comment: Hi @Ciwan, I edited the code snippet to have hover trigger on the surrounding dark-grey box. Let me know if this helps. Did you want the border to be removed if you hover over the image?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links can help:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/

[CSS create border on hover arround filled circle with empty space between circle and border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451607/css-create-border-on-hover-arround-filled-circle-with-empty-space-between-circle)